# Brake loop in html/javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a code to create a user log on form with two users. It works and the link opens when the right username and password is submitted. But it also prints the Error-message "Du har angivit ett felaktigt användarnamn eller lösenord! Det kan bero på att, du har skrivit fel användarnamn eller lösenord, att ditt konto har tagits bort eller att ditt konto har inte aktiverats ännu. Observera att det kan ta upp till en vecka för oss att aktivera ditt konto."

How can I stop the code from printing this when the right username and password is typed?

```
<html>
<head>
<title>
Login page
</title>
</head>
<body>

<form name="login">
Användarnamn <input type="text" name="userid"/>
Lösenord<input type="password" name="pswrd"/>
<input type="button" onclick="check(this.form)" value="Logga in"/>
<input type="reset" value="Rensa"/>
</form>
<script language="javascript">
function check(form)
{
if(form.userid.value == "user1" && form.pswrd.value == "pass 1")
{
window.open('link 1')
}

if(form.userid.value == "usre 2" && form.pswrd.value == "pass 2")
{
window.open('link 2')
}

else
{
document.write('Du har angivit ett felaktigt användarnamn eller lösenord! Det kan bero på att, du har skrivit fel användarnamn eller lösenord, att ditt konto har tagits bort eller att ditt konto har inte aktiverats ännu. Observera att det kan ta upp till en vecka för oss att aktivera ditt konto.');
}
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Surely having those passwords in the JavaScript is a temporary, prototype thing? You wouldn't really do that, right?

Comment: Well first of all you probably shouldn't have usernames and password in clear text on a web-page, or post it to a public site like this. Secondly, you should look at your `if` statements and their logic.

Answer (score 1):

The first `if` is standalone.

Use

```
if{}
else if{}
else{}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not a loop.

You're looking for `else if`:

```
function check(form) {
    if (form.userid.value == "klasurban" && form.pswrd.value == "97perdan") {
        window.open('https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_dvGLwXfQ0OUTVheVctMlNzS0E/edit?usp=sharing') /*opens the target page while Id & password matches*/
    } else if (form.userid.value == "klasurban2" && form.pswrd.value == "97dp97") {
// Here ^
        window.open('https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_dvGLwXfQ0OZEkwU0FvSEtTZHM/edit?usp=sharing') /*opens the target page while Id & password matches*/
    } else {
        document.write('Du har angivit ett felaktigt användarnamn eller lösenord! Det kan bero på att, du har skrivit fel användarnamn eller lösenord, att ditt konto har tagits bort eller att ditt konto har inte aktiverats ännu. Observera att det kan ta upp till en vecka för oss att aktivera ditt konto.');
    }
}
```

Now, if the first condition is true, only the block attached to it is run; if it isn't true, the next `if` is checked... Previously, since you weren't using `else` on your first `if`, the code after it (checking the second user) always ran.

Answer (score 0):

First you should refine your code by if.. else if..
Now, if you wish to break the code use return statement, it will work.

```
function check(form)
{
     if(form.userid.value == "klasurban" && form.pswrd.value == "97perdan")
     {
        window.open('https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_dvGLwXfQ0OUTVheVctMlNzS0E/edit?usp=sharing')/*opens the target page while Id & password matches*/
        return true;
     }

   if(form.userid.value == "klasurban2" && form.pswrd.value == "97dp97")
    {
      window.open('https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_dvGLwXfQ0OZEkwU0FvSEtTZHM/edit?usp=sharing')/*opens the target page while Id & password matches*/
     return true;
    }

    else
    {
          document.write('Du har angivit ett felaktigt användarnamn eller lösenord! Det kan bero        på att, du har skrivit fel användarnamn eller lösenord, att ditt konto har tagits bort eller att ditt konto har inte aktiverats ännu. Observera att det kan ta upp till en vecka för oss att aktivera ditt konto.');
          return true;
    }
  }
```